# how can i calculate total hrs in between logged in and logout with php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, mysqli

It is an attendance management system. 
One user' s working time schedule like this

Section 1
From: 10:00 To: 13:00

Section 2 
From 14:00   To 17:00
Break time 13 to 14 (1 hr)

User can multiple times logged and logout
If he/she  logged and logout like this ( it is saved in two array variable)

Logged: 10:00. logout 12:00
Logged: 12:30. logout 13:30
Logged: 13:45. logout 17:00
total hrs worked = 6 hrs 15 minutes

but i want to deduct user worked in between 13 to 14 ( break hrs)
so actual he worked total hrs - worked in between break hrs(ie 45 minutes) 
so how can solve this puzzle programmatically

Comment: Look into php's datetime class http://php.net/datetime

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add three Column In Your Database 1st Which Is Set Whenever The User Login
2nd Whenever The User Logout 3rd Whenever The User Logout The Time Will Be Added To It
For Example:

Login ----- Logout ------------------------------------------------------ And Sum

19:20 ----- 19:40 ---- 19:40 - 19:20 = 00:20 --- 00:00 + 00:20 = 00:20

5:15 ---------- 6:26 ------ 6:26 - 5:15 = 01:11 ---- 00:20 + 01:11 = 01:31

You Can Turn It Into Seconds